# C90 - Initialise aggregate type on the stack with non-const values

Tags: c

So say I want to initialise a new `vec3` **structure** for a shape I want to render with random coordinates; in modern C the code would look something like `struct vec3 coordinates = { rand_pos(), rand_pos(), rand_pos() };`. That's not the case with **C90** however, which requires *compile-time constants* to initialise the `struct`.

The only solution I could think of is to `malloc` the `struct` on the heap, initialise its members, and return its dereferenced value `return *coordinates;` However, since I'm not returning a pointer - *and I shouldn't return a pointer* - it makes the **API** seem *vague* as I still need to `free` the `struct` later, but I'd be passing an *address* rather than a *pointer* to `free`, which doesn't conform to the **API Guidelines**.

Comment: why not `struct vec3 coordinates;' coordinates.x = rand_pos(); coordinates.y = rand_pos(); coordinates.z = rand_pos();`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt That worked?!!!! How? Why wasn't my implementation working then? What does the compiler really mean with 'aggregate type', could you explain the problem to me? Post your answer by the way I want to mark this question as answered.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. Sorry but I can't say anything about the compiler error as you haven't posted the complete message. But you must not mix up initialization and assignment

Comment: Your way is not working because you use variable initialization which requires compile time constants. The working solution defines a variable without initialization and then assigns values to each element. For assignments no constant is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from defining the `struct` without initialisation (or with compile time constants) and assigning the desired values afterwards. Initialization and assignment isn't the same, so any compiler will accept that

```
struct vec3 coordinates;
coordinates.x = rand_pos(); 
coordinates.y = rand_pos(); 
coordinates.z = rand_pos();

return coordinates;
```